# Applying formula on dict and generating a result

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to apply some formula on existing dict and generate a new dict with new keys and calculated values in it.

Consider the dict which is as follows:

```
samples_dict = {'sample1': {u'Bhubaneswar': 21.0, u'Mumbai': 63.0},
               'sample2': {u'Bhubaneswar': 600.67, u'Mumbai': 1000.01},
               'sample3': {u'Bhubaneswar': 700.0, u'Mumbai': 2100.0},
               'sample4': {u'Bhubaneswar': 625.94, u'Mumbai': 1877.82},
           'sample5': {u'Bhubaneswar': 425.94, u'Mumbai': 877.82}}
```

Here I need to apply formula as follows:

```
formula = sample1+sample2
```

I am creating a list with keys which I need to be check for in dict using the formula. Also will create a new dict now.

```
sample_list = re.findall("\w+,*", formula)

new_dict = {sample: samples_dict[sample] for sample in sample_list if sample in samples_dict}
```

new_dict I created now is as follows now:

```
{'sample1': {u'Mumbai': 63.0, u'Bhubaneswar': 21.0}, 'sample2': {u'Mumbai': 1000.01, u'Bhubaneswar': 600.67}}
```

Now here I need to apply this formula in to this dict for creating a new item using the formula given.

Finally I need to merge with the base dict and I need the result now as follows:

I hope can use eval, someone help me how to do so.

```
samples_dict = {'sample1': {u'Bhubaneswar': 21.0, u'Mumbai': 63.0},
               'sample2': {u'Bhubaneswar': 600.67, u'Mumbai': 1000.01},
               'sample3': {u'Bhubaneswar': 700.0, u'Mumbai': 2100.0},
               'sample4': {u'Bhubaneswar': 625.94, u'Mumbai': 1877.82},
           'sample5': {u'Bhubaneswar': 425.94, u'Mumbai': 877.82},
           'sample6': {u'Bhubaneswar': 621.67, u'Mumbai': 1063.01}}
```

Some one help me with the same.

Comment: What kind of formula do you want to apply, and what is the pattern for the new key?

Comment: formula = sample1+sample2 , formula may be like this , some addition or subtraction

Comment: pattern is same as others already there in dict

Comment: @SergeBallesta check this

Comment: If you do not restrict the key pattern, a generic solution will be complex.

Comment: Anyway i will be giving a unique key name from one list

Comment: You lack a couple of things you need to solve this problema: a precise definition of what a formula is ("like this" or "for example" are not useful definitions) and and an algorithm to generate the new keys.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
import pprint


samples_dict = {
    'sample1': {u'Bhubaneswar': 21.0, u'Mumbai': 63.0},
    'sample2': {u'Bhubaneswar': 600.67, u'Mumbai': 1000.01},
    'sample3': {u'Bhubaneswar': 700.0, u'Mumbai': 2100.0},
    'sample4': {u'Bhubaneswar': 625.94, u'Mumbai': 1877.82},
    'sample5': {u'Bhubaneswar': 425.94, u'Mumbai': 877.82}
}


def formula(key1, key2, original_dict, new_name):
    temp_list = []
    original_dict[new_name] = {}

    for k, v in original_dict.items():
        if k == key1 or k == key2:
            temp_list.append(v)

    for k, v in temp_list[0].items():
        original_dict[new_name][k] = v + temp_list[1].get(k, 0)

    return original_dict


pprint.pprint(formula('sample1', 'sample2', samples_dict, 'sample6'))
```

Comment: thank u , But I need to different operation not only addition, For Ex: if formula is sample1+ sample2 need to do addtion if formula is sample1-sample2 , need to do subtraction , it will change dynamically

Comment: Also I need dict , Urs is basically nonetype

Comment: did you want to set subtraction sometime too?
It's good to add option for operand(sub or sum or ...)?

Answer (score 0):

Although you think it simple, it is a rather complex problem which really needs to be splitted down is smaller pieces.

Assumptions:

- the input dict is a dict of dicts
- all keys from the external dicts follow the pattern *prefix followed by a number*
- all inner dicts share the same keys and their values are numeric
- the input formula describes an arbitrary operation that should be applied to inner dicts (given by their keys), or more exactly on their inner values

First you need to process the keys of you dict. I assume that they are composed of an prefix followed by a number. Processing the keys will give the prefix (that will be used to process the formula) and the next unused key (max used number +1). Once this is specified it can be coded in Python, but as I have said in a comment it is the harder part:

```
def process_keys(dic):
    rx = re.compile("(\w*?)(\d+)")   # the pattern
    prefix = None
    mx = 0                           # maximum used value
    for key in dic.keys():
        m = rx.match(key)
        if m is None:                # every key must match the pattern
            raise ValueError(("key {} has not format "
                     +"prefix+number").format(key))
        if prefix is None:
            prefix = m.group(1)      # first processed key gives the prefix
        elif prefix != m.group(1):   # that must be used for all other ones
            raise ValueError(("key {} has not "
                     +"prefix {}").format(key, prefix))
        n = int(m.group(2))          # the current key value
        if n > mx: mx = n
    return "{}{}".format(prefix, mx+1), prefix
```

Then you must pre-process the formula. I assume a formula is a formula containing:

- keys from the dict that should be replaced by values from the inner dict
- operators (currently the following code only accept + and - operators but it could be extended to accept *, / and parentheses). The preprocessing will identify the keys and the operators, but as we have identified the prefix and thanks to the re module that will be the simplest part:

Code:

```
def process_formula(prefix, formula):
    rx = re.compile(r"({}\d+)|(\+|\-)".format(prefix))  # other operators could be added here
    return rx.findall(formula)
```

The interesting part is that it returns a list of 2-tuple in the form `(key, '')` or `('', op)` so it is trivial to differentiate keys from operators.

Now we can apply the formula to the dict. As *eval is evil*, I will use `ast.litteral_eval` and just replace the keys in the formula with the values from the inner dict and concatenate everything in a string:

```
def gen_value(dic, cmd):
    inner_keys = list(list(dic.values())[0].keys())  # the keys of the inner dicts
    val = {}                              # prepare the new dict
    for k in inner_keys:
        c = ''                            # initialize the formula
        for x in cmd:
            if x[0] == '':                # for an operator just copy it
                c += x[1]
            else:
                c += str(dic[x[0]][k])    # if it was a key, copy the inner value
        val[k] = ast.literal_eval(c)      # populate resulting dic
    return val
```

Ok, it is time to tie everything together:

```
def process(dic, formula):
    key_ref = process_keys(dic)
    cmd = process_formula(key_ref[1], formula)
    dic[key_ref[0]] = gen_value(dic, cmd)
```

This one modifies in place the original dict. It is left to the reader how to build a new dict...

Answer (score 0):

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) has built-in support for this kind of things and since your data is table-like, [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe) looks like a suitable data type to store them. This is what your data look like as a `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(samples_dict)
print(df)

             sample1  sample2  sample3  sample4  sample5
Bhubaneswar     21.0   600.67    700.0   625.94   425.94
Mumbai          63.0  1000.01   2100.0  1877.82   877.82
```

There is a method [`DataFrame.eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) that accepts strings and evaluates them as expressions depending on column labels.

```
formula = 'sample6 = sample1 + sample2'
df.eval(formula, inplace=True)
print(df)

             sample1  sample2  sample3  sample4  sample5  sample6
Bhubaneswar     21.0   600.67    700.0   625.94   425.94   621.67
Mumbai          63.0  1000.01   2100.0  1877.82   877.82  1063.01
```

In this case the definition of what a formula is comes from the specification of `.eval`, which may or may not fit your needs but it looks like ot will. I had to hardcode the new key in the formula since you did not provide any hints to generate it programmatically.

Comment: I need to use it without installing in my machine, I am using Redhat flavor, I just want to keep it as part of my project , I am not supposed to install it in my machine. Is there any possibility to use pandas like that

Comment: Not sure what you mean. In order to use any python library you need to copy certain files to a suitable location and that's called "installing the library". If you want to use only preinstaled libraries and those don't include pandas then you have to implement yourself the desired behaviour as suggested in [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41140091/2142055).